# How to insert elements into html document from string?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a string of html code stored in the localStorage, and what I want is to convert that string into a document and add that doc to an existing page. So far I came up with:

```
var data = localStorage.getItem("data");
var frag = document.createRange().createContextualFragment(data);
document.body.appendChild(frag);
```

but in the page the document fragment is just a simple string.

EDIT

I currently have the html:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

The string I saved for test purpose to the localStorage was `<p>Test</p>`

The result I am trying to get:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<p>Test</p>
</body>
</html>
```

The result I get:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
"<p>Test</p>"
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is the text in local storage HTML?

Comment: Yeah the string consists of HTML i forgot to mention that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the text in local storage is HTML, you can insert it at the beginning of, at the end of, in front of, or after any other existing element by using [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML). For example, to add to the document using the HTML in `html` inside the document body at the end:

```
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", html);
```

Example:

```js
const html = "<p>This is a new paragraph with <em>emphasized</em> text.</p>";
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", html);
```

```html
<p>This paragraph is already on the page.</p>
```

You can also use the [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) property of an existing element if you want to completely remove that element's current contents and replace them with what's defined in the HTML string:

```
someElement.innerHTML = html;
```

Example:

```js
const html = "This is the new content for the paragraph, with <em>emphasized</em> text.";
document.getElementById("existing-paragraph").innerHTML = html;
```

```html
<p id="existing-paragraph">This paragraph is already on the page.</p>
```

---

If it's not HTML, you can put it in an element (such as a `p` or `div`) and append that somewhere via [`appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) or [`insertBefore`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore), e.g.:

```
const p = document.createElement("p");
p.textContent = text;
document.body.appendChild(p);
```

Example:

```js
const text = "This is plain text, so things like <this> don't get misinterpreted as HTML.";
const p = document.createElement("p");
p.textContent = text;
document.body.appendChild(p);
```

Or just append it as raw text using [`createTextNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createTextNode):

```
const textNode = document.createTextNode(text);
document.body.appendChild(textNode);
```

Example:

```js
const text = "This is plain text, so things like <this> don't get misinterpreted as HTML.";
const textNode = document.createTextNode(text);
document.body.appendChild(textNode);
```

---

There's lots more to explore [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model).

---

In the comments we've figured out that the text in local storage has already been HTML-encoded, like this:

`&lt;p&gt;Testing &lt;em&gt; one two three&lt;/em&gt;&lt;/p&gt;`

That means that whatever code put the text in local storage encoded it before doing that (because local storage doesn't do that; it faithfully stores and returns the exact string you give it). The best solution is probably to update that code so that it doesn't do that.

If you can't update that code, you can interpret that text as HTML, you just have to do it *twice*: Once to interpret the `&lt;` and such so they're `<` again, then again to insert and parse the resulting HTML. The easy way to do that is to create an element (a `div` for instance), set its `innerHTML`, and then read its `textContent`. Here's an example:

Example:

```js
const textFromLocalStorage = "&lt;p&gt;Testing &lt;em&gt; one two three&lt;/em&gt;&lt;/p&gt;";
const div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = textFromLocalStorage;
const decodedHtml = div.textContent;
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", decodedHtml);
```

```html
<p>This paragraph is already on the page.</p>
```

Comment: When I use insertAdjacentHTML I only get [object DocumentFragment]

Comment: @NicolasStadler - `insertAdjacentHTML` takes the string directly. Don't create a document fragment, there's no need.

Comment: But I still get raw text in the doc. No matter what I try its always plain text

Comment: @NicolasStadler - In that case, please update your question with a [mcve], including the exact text you're using. `insertAdjacentHTML` **does** work with HTML, as you can see from the example in the answer. Perhaps the text has been HTML-encoded? (For instance, the string is `&lt;p>Testing &lt;em> one two three&lt;/em>&lt;/p>` or similar.)

Comment: You may found the prob bc with the code console.log(localStorage.getItem("data")) I am getting the string with &lt &gt for < and > maybe thats causing the Problem?

Comment: @NicolasStadler - Apparently it was encoded by the code that saved it, whatever code that is (local storage faithfully returns the string that was stored), so I can't tell you why it's encoded. :-| But I can tell you how to decode it -- I've added to the end of the answer above. :-)

Answer (score 0):

the arguments of [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) are [html elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element).
When you send to this a string, it converts to textnode.
You need to use [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) method

Comment: Please read the code. I am not passing in a string but a document Fragment.

Answer (score 0):

may be that ?

```
const DomParser = new DOMParser();
let data = localStorage.getItem("data");
let frag = DomParser.parseFromString( data, 'text/html').body.firstChild
document.body.appendChild(frag);
```

expecting data is only 1 html element (it can have many html  sub elements)

sample code

```js
const DomParser = new DOMParser();
let data = '<p>Test</p>' // eq: localStorage.getItem("data");
let frag = DomParser.parseFromString( data, 'text/html').body.firstChild;
document.body.appendChild(frag);
```

```css
p {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your try but it gets inserted as raw text as well.

Comment: @NicolasStadler but yet you indicated that it was html ! not simple text

Comment: I meant it outputs raw text into the doc.

Comment: @NicolasStadler this is so confusing, Please show a sample of your data of local storage and which html result you expect

Comment: @NicolasStadler I added a sample code to demonstrate my answer